# Turning search query into directory format

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, query-string

I want to turn my search URLs into directory format, meaning I want to turn:

> /search?q=hi

Into:

> /search/hi

How can this be done with .htaccess? I already have this in my .htaccess to remove the `.php` from the pages:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shoud do the trick (Remove your code for subtracting php extension):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/(.+) /search.php?q=$1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.+)
```

Comment: So this will turn the query string into directory format and remove `.php`? Thanks.

Comment: It will allow you to access both /search.php?q=search_term and /search/search_term